Wann darf man/sollte man „nicht“ ans Ende eines Satzes stellen, und wann nicht?
Ich habe immer geglaubt, dass es ganz richtig war – sogar manchmal am besten, wenn man das Negative betonen will – „nicht" ans Ende eines Satzes zu stellen:

Ich hörte den Mann auf der Strasse nicht.

Aber jemand hat mir gesagt, dass so ein Satz wie Folgender besser formuliert wäre:

Ich hörte nicht den Mann auf der Strasse.

Und ich weiß jetzt nicht, ob das eine stilistische Verbesserung ist, oder nur die Meinung dieser Person war, oder ob die beiden gleich richtig sind, und dass der einzige Unterschied ist, dass die zwei Sätze zwei leicht verschiedene Bedeutungen haben.
Es ist mir bewusst, dass die wahrscheinliche Antwort auf meine Frage lautet, „es kommt darauf an", d.h., dass viel von der Bedeutung oder vom Kontext abhängt.

Deine Formulierung ist perfekt. Der angebliche Verbesserungsvorschlag ist falsch.

Es ist zwar nicht die eigentliche Frage, aber korrekter wäre in beiden Sätzen "auf der Straße".

@TilmanSchmidt Stimmt. Perfekt bezog sich auf die Wortreihenfolge. Das in habe ich glatt übersehen.

Du machst es richtig. Lass dich von @Jankas Antwort nicht verwirren.


Ich hörte den Mann in der Strasse nicht.

Du stellst nicht niemals an das Ende. Du stellst nicht immer direkt vor das Ding, das du negieren willst. Der Grund, warum das nicht in deinem Beispiel am Ende steht, ist lediglich, dass das einzige Verb wegen der V2-Regel von seiner Grundposition am Ende des Satzes an die zweite Position im Satz verschoben wurde. Vergleiche das mal mit dem Nebensatz und mit dem Perfekt. Dort gilt nämlich entweder die V2-Regel nicht, oder es gibt ein zweites Verb, vor dem nicht dann steht:

Du weißt, dass ich den Mann in der Straße nicht hörte.
Ich habe den Mann in der Strasse nicht gehört.
Du weißt, dass ich den Mann in der Straße nicht gehört habe.

Und damit kannst du auch deine Frage selbst beantworten: Du hast das nicht vor das Verb des Prädikats gestellt, also die Aktion negiert. Dein Ratgeber hat stattdessen das ganze Prädikat inklusive des Akkusativobjektes und der dazugehörigen Ortsangabe negiert.
Beides ist möglich. Meistens will man aber nur die Aktion negieren. Dein Ratgeber hat dir also keinen guten allgemeinen Rat gegeben.
Im folgenden Fall würde das nicht vor den Mann in der Straße aber passen:

Ich hörte nicht den Mann in der Straße, sondern sah die Kinder auf dem Spielplatz.


"Ich hörte den Mann in der Straße nicht." ist richtig. Das nicht steht hier ganz klar am Ende. Deine Antwort mit der Aussage zu beginnen: "Du stellst nicht niemals an das Ende." kann für jemanden, der es bisher richtig gemacht hat und durch einen falschen Rat verunsichert wurde, nur so verwirrend sein, dass er jetzt überhaupt nicht mehr weiß, was richtig oder falsch ist. Vielleicht magst du deine Antwort ja noch einmal überarbeiten.

Ich finde, Jankas Antwort hat sehr guten Inhalt, aber der Anfang klingt irritierend. Ich darf vielleicht die folgende Einführung vorschlagen: Regel (1): Man stellt das Wort "nicht" immer direkt vor das Ding, das man negieren willt, AUSSER wenn es einen Konflikt mit der V2-Regel wegen des Verbs erstellt...; und dann kommt Regel (2): Wenn es einen Konflikt mit der V2-Regel erstellt, verschiebt man dann das Wort "nicht" am Ende des Satzes. Ist es richtig?

Wenn das "nicht" immer vor dem zu verneinenden Ding stehen muß, dann muß der Satz "Das glaube ich nicht." Stattdessen entweder "nicht das glaube ich" oder "nicht glaube ich das" oder "das glaube nicht ich" lauten. Stattdessen ist der Satz so, wie er anfangs dortsteht, völlig richtig und diese "Regel" falsch.

Du hast die Regel  nicht verstanden. Ein nicht „am Ende“ eines Satzes steht nicht an dessen Ende. Es folgen aus Sicht von nicht und anderen Adverbien immer noch die Verben des Prädikats. Das kannst du anhand meiner Beispiele auch sehr gut sehen. Es ist jedoch so, dass im Hauptsatz wegen der V2-Regel das letzte Verb vom Ende des Satzes an die zweite Position verschoben wird. Diese V2-Regel wird aber erst angewendet nachdem alle anderen Regeln zur Reihenfolge der Satzglieder (also auch die für nicht) angewendet wurden.

@Janka also deiner Meinung nach lautet der Satz "Ich den Mann auf der Straße nicht hörte". Und dann wird das Verb verschoben?

Richtig. Die V2-Regel ist die letzte Regel zur Satzstellung, die angewendet wird. Aus Sicht der anderen Satzstellungsregeln steht das konjugierte Verb immer noch da hinten.
